# Is there a way I can extract a specific word in a string if I only have part of the word?

Tags: python

I would like to extract a link from a string without questions such as "Go to", "Open", "take me to"... Is there a way I can extract a single word without spaces or punctuation as long as it has the domain in such word? (E.g. I want to find the link "google.com" in a string that contains "Go to google.com". I am looking for .com, .org, .net, etc to be in the link.) I want the extracted link to be in a variable form.
I use Python 3.7.3.

I tried `.split` and `".com" in i:`

The code is

```
i = input("What should I do? ")
    if ".com" in i or ".org" in i: 
        print(i)
```

I want the output to just include the link but it includes `"Go to (link)"`. Sadly I don't know how I can just output a link into a variable.

Comment: Words like "Such As" Make very poor requirements.  List all the possible prefixes that you want to handle and I bet from there on in the program gets a lot easier to write.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python string tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a regular expression for this task. For example:

```
import re


pattern = "(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+(-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*\.)+[\w]{2,}(\/\S*)?"

text_1 = "Go to google.com"
text_2 = "Read more on www.microsoft.com"
text_3 = "available at http://wikipedia.org"

texts = [text_1, text_2, text_3]

for text in texts:
    matched_urls = re.finditer(pattern, text)  # collect all matches
    extracted_urls = [m.group(0) for m in matched_urls]  # extract matched strings 
    print(extracted_urls)
```

And the output will be:

```
['google.com']
['www.microsoft.com']
['http://wikipedia.org']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You fixed my issue and now it's working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is regular expression. You can define regex pattern to extract from a string. [Python re][1] library is very rich and has lot of useful utilities to use from. Sample below:

```
>>> import re
>>> y = "Go to google123.net"
>>> pattern = r'([\w\d]+\.(com|org|net))'
>>> re.findall(pattern, y)
[('google123.net', 'net')]
>>> re.search(pattern, y).group(0)
'google123.net'


  [1]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
```